# High voltage drop when load is connected

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, electrical

I'm getting 6 volts open circuit voltage. Whenever I connect a load (resistors), there is a huge drop in voltage values. Does it signify power input is less or is there any other reason for the same?

I'm using a thermoelectric module as a power source.

Comment: google `ohm's law` to learn the relationship between voltage, resistance and current ...... hint: the power supply has some internal resistance

Comment: What are you connecting this load to? There is not enough information for an answer that might be relevant to your case.

Comment: Shivam - Although we can guess at the likely cause, there are several possible variations. Therefore please *edit the question* and add more details and context e.g. What circuit are you building and why? Add some clear, in-focus photos of your hardware so that we can see the length and type of wiring. Add photos of the battery and resistors. What is the battery type / model (at a guess, for 6V it's SLA)? What value are the resistors? Why did you choose that value? Do you have a multimeter and experience using it? If so, did you take any measurements already? See here: [ask] Thanks.

Comment: When voltage drop is 50% you know that source resistance is equal to load. Load regulation error defines this relationship from resistance ratio or simply Ohm’s Law sharing the same current. If there is active current limiting occurring, then it may be non-linear.

Comment: Because your thermoelectric module is not enough of a power source.  Edit your question stating resistance, current of load.

Answer (score 2):

Like some of the comments say your problem seems related to the internal resistance of your power supply. All voltage sources have some internal resistance that effectively limits the amount of voltage they can deliver to a load. For example, take a look at the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmd6j3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In an ideal world, V1 would have no internal resistance. We do not live in an ideal world, so this voltage supply has an internal resistance, which I've made to be 1 ohm. In this circuit, where we have a 1k ohm load, that internal resistance has little effect on circuit performance. To calculate the voltage across the load, we can use the voltage divider equation, so Vload = V1*(Rload/(Rload+Rint)), so Vload = 1*(1000/1001) = .99 volts. So the large Rload means almost all of the voltage from V1 is appears across Vload. Internal resistance becomes a problem when Rload becomes too small.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxAbFP.png)</sup>

For this circuit, Vload = 1*(1/1+1) = .5. Bad! In short, if you have a crummy voltage source (high internal resistance), use large valued resistors (1k+). You could also read about ohm's law, voltage dividers, and thevenin equivalent circuits to have a better idea of whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Every power supply has an internal resistance even if it is very small.

if there is not an internal resistance you don't get a drop of voltage in the load

Let consider this circuit with :
R int=0   ohm,
R load=0.1 ohm
[image]
if we calculate the total current we get

I=V/R
I=6/0.1= 60A

the voltage across the load equal V=I*R load

V load= 60*0.1= 6v  ie: no drop of voltage

but if we change this circuit and we use a resistor of 10 ohm in load and Rintarnal considered as 2 ohm
[image]

we get:

I=V/(R load+R int)
I=6/(2+10)
I=0.5 A

the voltage across the load equal V=I*R load

V load= 0.5*10= 5v  ie: there is a drop of voltage